# How to return extra message while return type is T?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a function:

```
public async Task<T> PostAsync<T>(string url,string parameters)
{
    var response=await httpClient.PostAsync(url,data);
    if(response is null)
    {
        return default;
    }
}
```

if response is null I can only return default. now I want to add extra message to T that "response is null"

how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return an object and a message, you would be better off creating a ResponseObject DTO to take both of those as parameters. That way you can add extra information to return if you want like error codes or other data.

Something like:

```
public class ResponseDTO<T>
{
    public T Object { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public async Task<ResponseDTO<T>> PostAsync<T>(string url,string parameters)
{
    var response=await httpClient.PostAsync(url,data);
    if(response is null)
    {
        return new ResponseDTO<T> {
            Object = default(T),
            Message = "Response is null"
        };
    }

    return new ResponseDTO<T> {
        Object = response
    };

}
```

Comment: I know what you said.but it is not convenient right?If I want to get the data I have to write response.Object.Id

Comment: Perhaps, but you really only have to assign the object to new variable and access that way.